# No Google play services available on GoogleTV (Android 3.2)?

Tags: google-tv, android-3.2-honeycomb

According to http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

"A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and includes Google Play Store."

it should be possible to use the Google play services. I tried it with the normal one and the one for Froyo in the SDK Manager. But both results in missing the services, when running the APK on the device (Sony nsz -gs7).

Are Googles informations misleading or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found a working solution:

Use https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_3225130_r10.zip

in your project setup. This google play services library is compatible with android 3.2

Comment: While it looks like it works, no GoogleCloud-Messages are able to be received, while the developer console states it as successful delivered. Same code works on Android 4.x... @Google what is wrong with Google Play Services on Android 3.2?